# How to replace Day of TDateTime type on runtime

Tags: c++builder-xe, tdatetime

I have TDateTime variable named dtBegin. dtBegin is containing value "7/3/2000".
I need to replace the Day only with "2" to change the value into "2/3/2000".

How to do this? I've been suggested to use RecodeDay() method in C++ Builder XE but the method is not worked. I put the dtBegin on the method to be:

```
RecodeDay(dtBegin, 2);
```

But the method is not returning the value that I want.

Is there any method to do this? Help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`RecodeDay`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.DateUtils.RecodeDay) is a function declared as `System::TDateTime __fastcall RecodeDay(const System::TDateTime AValue, const System::Word ADay);`, so you need to store the return value:

```
dtBegin = RecodeDay(dtBegin, 2);
```